# Display message in landscape mode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, landscape, messagebox

How can I display `MessageBox.Show()` method as landscape mode in a Windows Phone 7 application?

Here is my code:

```
MessageBox.Show("Game Over Earned money:" + Prise[CorrectAnswers]);
```

I should display the message as landscape mode. Is that possible?

Comment: Is your app a game ? Do you use XNA ?

Comment: no , silverlight phone application.

Comment: So you want to force the message box to be displayed in landscape mode irrelevant of the base page orientation ?

Comment: yeah exactly ı want this

Comment: I'm not sure why would you want to do that and I don't think it's possible to do it with the default silverlight or xna message box. The only thing that comes to my mind is to use a custom message box / user control and use something like CompositeTransform.Rotation or similar in order to change the orientation.